# What is the best algorithm for detecting the texture of a person's clothes in real-time for a mobile robot?

Tags: computer-vision, image-processing, python, real-time, robotics

I am working on the human following robot. the robot extracts a feature of clothes's texture and distinguishes between the people that they stand up in front of the robot. So, the robot needs that it will be robust and fast.

Comment: This is a very broad question.  It sounds like you're asking an awful lot here.  The first step would be to define what you mean by "detecting the texture"; what kind of output you'd want.  The next step would be to acquire a labelled dataset.  The next step would be to try something and see how well it works.  This kind of work tends to require a lot of experimentation and trial and error.  I'm not sure that this kind of question, where you want someone to tell you how to approach an entire project, is a good fit here -- I'm not sure there will be any short answer.

Comment: Thanks, D.W., all I need name of the best algorithm so that fast and robust in real-time. I have experience in how to label and so on.